# How I can make internationalization changes js file for alert

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

How can I make internationalization changes js file for alert, without passing value through template.

I have 'messages' & messages.es-ES file in conf folder.

Comment: You can use gettext libarry it have implementation in lot of languages. including javascript and scala.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I have similar problem in an older version of play framework (2.2.x), that I had solved by writing a twirl template like this:

```
    @()
    @import play.api.Play.current
    var myI18n = (function() {

            var messages = @Html("{" + Messages.messages.flatMap(_._2).map(mess => s""""${mess._1}":"${mess._2}"""").mkString(", ") + "}")
        return {
            getMessage: function (key) {
                if(messages.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    return messages[key];
                }
                else return key;
            }
        };
    });
```

In this way, i build at runtime a js file with my messages library and with a basic function for retrieving. 
Then I expose an action who returns this (obiviusly need cache by locale):

```
public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(views.html.i18n.render());
}
```

and include in pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@controllers.routes.I18nJs.javascriptRoutes()"></script>
```

Finally, I can retrieve the value of messages key with a sample `myI18n().getMessage("my.message.key")`